# Integral of a Continued Fraction

Tags: calculus, integration, continued-fractions

How might one go about evaluating the following integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{K}_{j=0}^{\infty}(F_{j}e^{-x^2})dx$? Where$\mathrm{K}$ denotes a continued fraction and $F_j$ is the jth fibonacci number. Looking at the graph of the function, it has to be a positive number but I have no clue about how to integrate it analytically.